# Add children objects to Parent object list and get properties

Tags: java, object

Consider this scenario please

```
abstract class Human{
   String ID;
   String demographic;
   int knoledgeSpreadSpeed;

   
}

class Student extends Human {
   private Human connectedTo;
   private final String connectionAddress;

   public Student(String ID, String demographic, int knoledgeSpreadSpeed, String connectionAddress) {
        super(ID, demographic, knoledgeSpreadSpeed);
        this.connectionAddress = connectionAddress;
    }
}

class Professor extends Human{
    private int numberOfAvailableMentoringSlots;
    private static HashMap<String, Human> socialConnections = new HashMap<>();

    public Professor(String ID, String demographic, int knoledgeSpreadSpeed, int numberOfAvailableMentoringSlots) {
        super(ID, demographic, knoledgeSpreadSpeed);
        this.numberOfAvailableMentoringSlots = numberOfAvailableMentoringSlo;
    }
}

List <Human> humans = new ArrayList<>();
{
  humas.add(new Stunet(...));
  humans.add(new Proffessor(....));
}
```

when I look over the human list, I want to get the communication address of Student

this is what I have tried

```
for(Student student : humans){
   student.get(comminicationAddress)
}
```

How can I get the properties of the student by looping in the humans list?

Comment: As-is, the code won't compile. For one, you have several typos. For another, `Student` and `Professor` do not stand in an inheritance relationship to `Human`. For a third, `List <Human> humans = new huma ArrayList<>();` is no valid java syntax.

Comment: thank you, I will correct my mistakes.

Comment: The code will still not compile. `public Computer(String ID, String demographic, int knoledgeSpreadSpeed, String connectionAddress)` and `public Switch(String ID, String demographic, int knoledgeSpreadSpeed, int numberOfAvailableMentoringSlots)` are not legal methods.

Comment: Anyway, if we assume that those issues are sorted out and standard getters do exist, we can do the following: `humans.stream().filter(Student.class::isInstance).map(Student.class::cast).map(Student::getConnectionAddress).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Constructor names does not match class names

Comment: thanks all for the comments.